# Вопрос о БД SQlite

Tags: sqlite

Можно ли в sqlite задавать связи между таблицами, как например в sql server или access? И как потом ее посмотреть в готовой базе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно. Изучайте документацию: http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

В готовой базе с помощью sql-запроса посмотреть список связей между таблицами (foreign key constraints) не получится. Таблица sqlite_master не хранит о них информации. Однако, это можно сделать практически в любой IDE для sqlite.